# No data received error in Chrome In Ruby application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, sinatra

I am new in Ruby. I am using Sinatra as framework. I am working on a project that involves a few mysql queries taking reasonable amount of time. Actually there is a front end where user can input the parameters and press view button in response to which the query fires and at the completion of them view is populated.

But the problem is that due to reasonable amount of time taken by the query it is showing **"no data received"** in chrome though the query is executing in the backend. I don't know how to fix that, I have tried many ways to optimise the query but actually the data is much so I don't think any further optimisation possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using GET request to run the query?

Comment: What server are you using? Maybe it times out before the query completes.

Comment: I am using thin server.

Comment: Please include some code...relevant view + route code, at least. Have you tried browsers other than chrome? I would assume so since you've tagged chrome.